Enforce a post condition in a library
I am creating a unique ID generator. Let's call it - UID service (our library - a 3rd party library) that would have a function to request a unique ID, something like getUniqueIdentifier which would return a unique ID (Let's say our library - this 3rd party library already has all the configuration like db credentials and other stuff hard-coded inside it)
There will be clients requesting for unique IDs from this UID service. The clients will use those IDs for inserting some records in its own separate database.
So let's say when a call is made and a unique ID is fetched successfully from UID service, it can successfully be used by the client to insert into the database, or a failure may occur with the insert.
Also, let's say there is another function to return an identifier to the UID service in case a failure occurred while using it. Something like returnIdentifier(int id)
My question here is, how do I enforce returning the ID in case of failure automatically when a failure happens while inserting into the database, so that the clients will not miss the step of manually adding the retuning back part.

It all depends on what the consequence of duplicate ids or having non-used ids marked as used will be - in general, because of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem you'll have to accept some sort of risk of either case being true (i.e. what if the system that requested the id dies before it can notify the other part that the id wasn't used). If you can accept potential duplicates (and not having unused ids are more important), you can set a TTL before the id usage has to be acknowledged (instead of returned), and if it isn't ACK-ed before ttl, it'll be marked as available

The common solution is to go "consider all requested ids as used, no need to 'return' them". As soon as you start having distributed systems, having a central uuid location can become a bottleneck, so you have local generation of unique ids (such as Twitter's Snowflake) instead.

The question here is not to waste IDs or what is performant.... It is to ask if there is any code construct / design pattern to allow such a case to mandate the return of the ID, in case of failure..... Something like try with resource in java....

Would the get-the-id-try-to-use-it-but-return-it-in-case-of-error operation be in-process or out-of-process?

Hopefully in-process, it's fine if out-of-process as well

If the service and its client communicates out-of-process, as the commenters imply, this is a really, really hard problem.
If we assume that client code communicates with the UID service with a normal method call, on the other hand, we can use a Command object and encapsulate in a try/catch block.
So, the UID service might offer a method like this (C#-like pseudocode):
public void WithId(IUidCommand cmd)
{
    var uid = // generate the UID here
    try
    {
        cmd.Use(uid);
    }
    catch // list the exceptions that you handle here
    {
        // recycle uid
        // rethrow?
    }
}

where IUidCommand is an interface:
public interface IUidCommand
{
    void Use(int uid);
}

Alternatively, you could define the Use method as one that returns a bool, and instead of the try/catch have the UID service recycle the ID if the command returns false.
